# Visual Studio 2015 not installing Mysql.data in NuGet

Tags: mysql, azure, visual-studio-2015, uwp, mysql.data

**UWP App not being able to work with MySql**

I have made an app in UWP and instead of using SQLLite which seems to be the norm for Visual Studio 2015 I want to use MySql. I have already connected my Azure mysql database to Visual Studio via the 'Server Explorer'.

I'm using MySQL Workbench to update my tables within my connected database from Azure but I cannot actually write any code to access my tables as whenever I try to install MySql.data/.entity/etc in the NuGet Package Manager I get an error.

[nuget error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElVyl.png)

I tried downloading the Mysql installer, the Mysql drivers for Ado and ODBC. I even tried downloading the MySql for Visual Studio option as I found out that Visual Studio is not compatibile with MySql and instead requires the MySql for Visual Studio download but I still have errors whenever I try to use MySql in my code as I need an assembly reference for it but I'm having no luck in being able to get one that doesn't error.

Does anybody  have any idea how I could actually use MySql within Visual Studio 2015?

This is what I've been using as my guideline but I can't seem to get past the Mysql.data errors when installing.

http://web3.codeproject.com/Articles/1074242/Designig-your-Azure-MySQL-DB-with-a-UWP-Demo

I have seen a lot of people talk about this but there is no one straightforward fix (I've tried a lot of the fixes, one in particular being to use Vs13 to install Mysql in the Nuget package manager and then it should update within VS15 but as my app is a UWP VS13 does not actually load/read it so that idea isn't good to me, might help anyone else though)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 6.7, Connector/Net fully supports building Windows Store apps. But using Connector/Net RT is not by install the Nuget package, it just reference the `MySql.Data.RT.dll` assembly according to [MySQL Connector/Net Developer Guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-rt.html):

> Using Connector/Net RT is easy. Simply create a Windows Store application using Visual Studio and then reference the MySql.Data.RT.dll assembly in your project. The code you write should be exactly the same as for normal Connector/Net (including using same namespace MySql.Data.MySqlClient) except for the differences listed above.

You may find this dll at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.79\Assemblies\RT` if you have install the connector. You can also download the [mysql-connector-net-6.7.9-noinstall.zip](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=459596) to find this file inside the folder. I also have a MySql UWP sample before and has the dll [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/CMVVM). Right click your project and add reference for this it will work.

More details please reference [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-MySQL-database-with-03c1e9c7)